# Manually validate a text

Tags: validation, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to validate a text (JSON) received from an ajax request.

```
val myValidation: Mapping[String] = ///...

def setNewNameAjax = Action { request =>
  val json = Json parse request.body.asJson.get.toString
  val name = (json \ "name").toString()
  // how do I manually validate "name" by myValidation?
}
```

So the aim is to validate `name` using my validator `myValidation`. And, preferably, sensibly  return the result in case of a validation error. How do I do this?

The goal is not to validate JSON in particular. The goal is to validate any kind of a text using a custom vaditor (in this case, it's `myValidation`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a bad idea to validate against a `Mapping`. A `Mapping` should be used to handle a form field and it expects a `Map[String, String]` instead of just a value to be validated.

However, you can validate a value using a `Mapping[T]`. It's just a little trickier. In general I'd advise to validate a `String` value using `Constraint[String]` but here's the working code:

```
val myValidation: Mapping[String] = ///...

def setNewNameAjax = Action { request =>
  val json = Json parse request.body.asJson.get.toString
  val name = (json \ "name").toString()
  //one mapping may have multiple constraints, so run the validation for all of them and collect the list of ValidationResults
  val validationResults = myValidation.constraints.map(_(name))
  //filter the list - leave only the conditions that failed
  val failedValidationResults = validationResults.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Invalid])
  failedValidationResults match {
    case Nil => //Validation OK, no constraints failed
    case _ => //Validation failed, assemble the message and inform the user
  }
}
```

Comment: if it were a plain text or xml, would it be possible to do the same? If not then it's not what I want.

Comment: there are 2 conditions: to use myValidation: Mapping[T] and not to use JSON in particular.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question. I edited the post to match your comments

Comment: Thank you. `In general I'd advise to validate a String value using Constraint[String]` - but how, via myConstraint.map(...)?

Comment: Via `myConstraint(...)` or `myConstraint.apply(...)`

Comment: but what's the difference? I'll end up with the list of errors anyway or with a nil list and these are what I need.

Comment: Yes, but `Mapping` is actually not intended for plain validation. As play documentation says, `A mapping is a two-way binder to handle a form field` and it's primary purpose is to validate and bind the value somewhere, and a `Constraint` is just a validator for this value. Roughly a `Mapping` is a more specific thing that contains constraints

Comment: But if I have a few constants, it's better to combine them into one Mapping[T] and validate only one time rather then manually validate the input for each constraint and then combine the results.

Comment: It's up to you now to decide :) Yes, you can leave it as it is and it should work. Just keep in mind that it can be a bit more difficult for others to figure out what you are trying to do with `Mapping`. `Constraint` is just a bit more obvious